# Fire RadioButton checked routed event programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf, events, wpf-controls

Is there anyway to raise a `RadioButton` checked routed event from code, in order to handle it in a parent control?

This is the situation:

```
var radio = new RadioButton();
radio.IsChecked = true;
radio.RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(RadioButton.CheckedEvent));
```

The third line does not work.

Googling, I found another way based on the `RadioButtonAutomationPeer`, but I had not found a way to make it work.

Does someone have some hint?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why you want to do this?

Comment: You should never raise events on UI elements you are not implementing. Usually, you want to do this because something else is wrong.

Comment: you could always refactor the RadioButtonEvent code into a method and call it later when needed

Comment: I do have to bubble the event in order to handle it in a parent control

Answer (score 0):

```
var radio = new RadioButton();
radio.CheckedChanged +=new EventHandler(radio_CheckedChanged);
radio.IsChecked = true;

private void radio_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        if (radio.Checked)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("true");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("false");
        }

}
```

Comment: This is good if I needed to handle the event directly in the RadioButton control, but I do have to bubble the event in order to handle it in a parent control

Answer (score -1):

You can get Radio checked event programmatically but not directly add on page/form.
you have to create panel or some else controler in which you can add this Radio Button like this

### this is your .aspx page

```
<div>
        <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnl1">
    </asp:Panel>            
</div>
```

### this is your aspx.cs page

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var radio = new RadioButton { Checked = false, AutoPostBack = true, Text = "Click" };
    radio.CheckedChanged += radio_CheckedChanged;
    pnl1.Controls.Add(radio);
}

void radio_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Comment: This is not `ASP.NET`.

Comment: @AnatoliyNikolaev Not ASP.NET then what?

Comment: OP don't use `ASP.NET`, he use a `WPF + C#`. Looks the tags.